# Skip YAML 'frontmatter' (for middleman) in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, actionview, middleman

I have recently seen that middleman view files are very useful for rails, as one could easily use them with a purposedly built view model/decorator, and some general helper that is able to expose the `data` object to the view.

Now, The problem is per-page data (which middleman stores in the frontmatter) as rails won't take it into account - probably.

So my question (still very fuzzy) is: How can I make ActionView know about the frontmatter, and be able to inject it in the `current_page.data` object?

This could be quite interesting, as a team of designers could work with a much simpler environment, and then the resulting views could be used untouched in the main application.

Example:

```
# /sources/views/users/index.html.slim
---
title: My Title
subtitle: My Subtitle
---

header
  h1
    = current_page.data.title
    small<
      = current_page.data.subtitle

table
  thead
    tr
      td = t(:name)
      td = t(:email)
  tbody
    - data.users.each do |user|
      tr
        td = user.name
        td = user.email
```

The `data.users` object is provided by the controller, but how about the specific data in the page?